# Why does GPG ask for passhrase when ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf exists?

Tags: security, gnupg

Using GPG 2.2.19, libgcrypt 1.8.5 on Ubuntu 20.04.3

I use GPG to sign git commits and to decrypt password savec in the Unix Password manager [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/). Everything is working perfectly. ie. GPP works happily to sign my commits and to decrypt my pwd queries via `pass`. GPG never asks for a passphrase.

When I export the private key for backup using `gpg --export-secret-keys --armor`. I notice the pinentry screen is graphical and it blocks the entire screen (two monitors actually) until I enter correctly the passphrase. Not sure if the entire screen block is intentional design. But I find that rather inconvenient. Searching around, I learnt that I just need to create `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` and configure the pinentry program. Which I did by:

```
cat > ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf << EOF
# The UI to prompt for passphrase. Possible values: ll /usr/bin/pinentry*
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses

# set the timespan (in seconds) after entering your password. Default: 7200 seconds (2 hours)
# 1 week = 604800 secs, 30days = 2592000, 1Y = = 31536000 seconds.
max-cache-ttl 604800

# sets the timeout (in seconds) after the last GPG activity. Default 600 seconds (10 minutes)
default-cache-ttl 604800
EOF

# Reload config
gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye
```

I have also add `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` in `~/.zshrc`.

The `pinentry-curses` program does achieve the desired effect, which is to display a  the pinentry screen in terminal mode. However, now every time the computer restarts, anytime GPG is used, whether to decrypt (via `pass` utility) or via `git` to sign commits, the pinentry screen pops up to ask for the passphrase. After that the passphrase is cached and pinentry no longer pops up ... until the next OS restart.

It is probably a good things to ask for passphrase at each reboot. But I get used to GPG not asking for the passphrase. And my work setup allows for this kind of laxity for now. When I rename or delete the `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` file, then GPG works as before, ie. decrypt and sign without asking for the passphrase.

**QUESTION**: what is the reason GPG "forget" the passphrase at each OS restart when the `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` file exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gpg-agent does not have any "persistent" password storage of its own. It *always* forgets passwords after a reboot and has to call pinentry for the first time.

However, all the standard graphical pinentries have their own integration with *libsecret* persistent password storage – which means they'll store the passphrase in GNOME Keyring. Whenever gpg-agent runs the full-screen "pinentry-gnome3" after reboot, the pinentry app just directly returns the passphrase from GNOME Keyring without needing to actually prompt for anything.

Meanwhile, the text-mode pinentry apps (pinentry-curses, pinentry-tty) do not have libsecret integration, as they're meant to be used in environments where something like GNOME Keyring wouldn't survive.

To have this again, you will need to switch to either `pinentry-gtk-2` or `pinentry-qt`.

---

Side note: I suspect that GnuPG's choice to invoke the full-screen prompter provided by GNOME Shell was very deliberate, as even *before* GNOME 3, the simple `gtk-2` pinentry already had an option to globally grab all input events regardless of focus; this was meant to prevent users accidentally typing their password into the wrong window. (I think this was just relatively recently changed to be *off* by default.)

Comment: Thanks, now it all makes senses.

Comment: "this was meant to prevent users accidentally typing their password into the wrong window" maybe this is rather to prevent possible keylogger from sniffing your keystrokes? Any of us probably have already made many thousands logins of various types. I don't remember a single time where I enter the password in an unrelated window.