# GPG not restarting the GPG-Agent

Tags: encryption, arch-linux, gnupg, password-management, gpg-agent

I am trying to restart the gpg-agent with the command:

```
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
```

This should, according to multiple answers on this forum, lock my GPG-Keys and ask for a password, when I want to use a key to unlock e.g. a file. With most keys, this is done and I am prompted for a password.
The problem is, that the key I am using for `pass` as a password manager is not asking for a password, it is just unlocking my passwords / copying them to the clipboard without any password prompt. The issue persists when I reload the gpg-agent with the command above and when I restart the computer. I tried to change the config of `gpg` to auto-empty the cache after some time but it only empties the cache for other keys.

Does anyone face a similar problem or has an idea, where the issue might be rooted? I will of course provide more info if that's the case, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Looks like the exact opposite problem of https://superuser.com/questions/1686827/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *does,* in fact, make gpg-agent forget the passphrases it has cached. However, as soon as gpg-agent launches `pinentry` to prompt you for the passphrase again, pinentry automatically retrieves it from *another* password manager via libsecret.

(Notice the "Remember password" checkbox whenever you're entering a GnuPG passphrase.)

In most cases, libsecret will be accessing GNOME Keyring, which uses your login password to encrypt data. (Other backends are available; KeePassXC is commonly used.) You can see your passwords stored there using the `secret-tool` command:

```
secret-tool search --all xdg:schema org.gnupg.Passphrase
```

To remove the entries, use `secret-tool clear` on them.

`seahorse` allows you to manage GNOME Keyring contents graphically (technically it'll manage whatever app is currently providing the libsecret service, but it's *meant* for use with GNOME Keyring).

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I have been wondering for some time where the issue comes from.